# Warum nicht Dativ in "Er bricht den Stab über ihn"?

Tags: grammar, phrase, idiom, grammatical-case

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/brechen) soll bei dieser Redewendung der Akkusativ genommen werden:

> er brach den Stab über ihn (*nicht ihm*);

Bei Google finden sich aber beide Varianten. Warum wird nun Akkusativ empfohlen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Akkusativ wird nicht empfohlen, er ist hier obligatorisch. ;)

Der Stab wurde zwar über *dem* Delinquenten gebrochen (über seinem Haupt), aber das Urteil wurde über *den* Übeltäter gesprochen.

Es geht hier nicht über den Ort (über dem Kopf) des Brechens, sondern um das Sinnbild des Urteilsspruchs.

Zur Klarstellung: Der Richter zerbrach den Richterstab über dem zu Tode Verurteilten. Siehe [hier](http://www.zweideutig.de/alte_redewendungen.htm), auch wenn dort der Dativ fälschlicherweise verwendet wird. :)

Comment: I have carefully read your analysis and also the reference provided, and I cannot for the life of me see how either justifies the accusative. The reference is titled "Über jemandem den Stab brechen" and although I am only a student of German, the "m" in jemandem tells me it is the dative case. The only possible argument I can make for the accusative would be that "uberbrechen den Stab" is a separable verb phrase with the meaning "to pass judgement on", in which case it would arguably take the accusative. But I do not find this argument being made.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear enough, @Marty. Let me try it again. First, there is an accusative, because Duden says so ;) Second, there is the accusative, because it is used figuratively. It is used the same way like "Urteil über jemanden sprechen" where also the accusative is used. My reference uses it wrong! I told that in my last sentence: "Look here, even if there was the dative (incorrectly) used." Maybe I should have been more precise here. I'll add the "incorrect". I put the reference in for the historical background only.

Comment: As an English speaker, we don't have very good intuition over the case taken by prepositions: but it wasn't clear to me that your "urteil sprechen uber jemanden" was strictly analogous to "brechen den Stab uber jemanden". In the first case you are pronouncing judgement *concerning* someone, in the second you are breaking the staff *over* someone. The two prepositions are different enough that I don't find it convincing that they must take the same case. But if you say that the staff-breaking case evolved out of analogy from the judgement case, I suppose that would explain it.

Comment: @Marty: To be clear: If you take a staff and break it above the head of somebody, then it is dative (über ihm). Only the switch to a synonym/analogy of a judgement makes the difference here.

Answer (score 2):

Es kommt natürlich darauf an, was Du sagen willst. Keiner der Ausdrücke ist generell richtiger als der andere.

Falls Du mit dem Ausdruck den realen Sachverhalt (Stab über einer Person zerbrechen) beschreiben willst, musst Du den Dativ verwenden.

Andernfalls -bei Gebrauch des Ausdrucks als Redewendung- ist der Akkusativ sinnvoller (aber m.E. nicht unbedingt erforderlich), um den Ausdruck grammatikalisch von der Sachverhaltsbeschreibung abzugrenzen.

Hier wird der Akkusativ verwendet, um den Ausdruck in die Nähe von "über jemanden reden", "jemanden verurteilen" zu rücken.

Answer (score 1):

Die Redewendung lautet richtig "über jemand(en) den Stab brechen". Wenn hier auch der Dativ "über jemandem" gefunden wird, so kann das nur ein Hinweis darauf sein, dass nicht jedermann klar ist, auf welche Form sich die Redewendung eingespielt hat.
Logischerweise wäre auch der Dativ zu vertreten, aber Formeln haben nun mal ihre Eigenheiten.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consult Curme on this one. I think it may have to do with 'pronounced transitive force'. Dative is often used when things are at rest or localized (*er geht in der Stadt*: he is walking *in* the city)  but accusative when motion into or force is involved (*er geht in die Stadt*: he walks *into* the city)